# Changing/Casting strings to date data type in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, casting, sqldatatypes, opencsv, import-csv

I have imported a csv file in my postgresql database. The file contains a column of dates. I have imported that column in 'varchar' form. the column contains dates that are not in one particular format, meaning some dates are dd/mm/yyyy and some in mm/dd/yyyy. Now I'm trying to cast these strings into date format, but Im unable to do. postgresql gives error 'field value out of range'.
What should I do? Should I make date format consistent in csv file or is there any method in postgres?
Sample data ;
project_date 1. '23/10/2022'
2. '12/31/2022'

I am trying to get answers from the fellows here

Comment: You will need to use `to_date` from here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and provide proper format template e.g. `select to_date('23/10/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'); 2022-10-23` or `select to_date('12/31/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY'); 2022-12-31`.  It would be easier to provide a consistent date format in the CSV file. **FYI**, the format you choose should match the `datestyle` as returned by `show datestyle`

Comment: The `datestyle` options are described here [Date/time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT) *8.5.2. Date/Time Output*

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is get a specific date format (**all dates the same format**), preferably ISO-8601 (yyyy-mm-dd). If you cannot do that then you can build a function that tests the date formats permitted with the `to_date` and returns the first successful conversion. Something like:

```
create or replace function unscrew_date(should_be_a_date text) 
  returns date
 language plpgsql 
as $$
declare 
    k_date_formats constant text[] = array['dd/mm/yyyy','mm/dd/yyyy'];

    dt_fmt text;
begin 
    foreach dt_fmt in array k_date_formats 
    loop 
        begin 
          return to_date(should_be_a_date,dt_fmt); 
        exception 
          when datetime_field_overflow then null;
          when invalid_datetime_format then null;
          when others then raise exception 'Unexpected error: %, %',sqlstate, sqqlerrm;
        end; 
    end loop; 
    return null;
end; 
$$;
```

However this still leaves a whole set of dates the cannot be known correct; any day less than 13. For example `'12/08/2020'`, is that December 8, or August 12. The above function will always return August 12,2020.

The only valid workable solution is **standardize the date format**. Then deal with that format.